# mod_rewrite and routing to code igniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have been using code igniter as a subdirectory of a site and have several instances of if on one server.  Each instance is considered a separate application, but all under the same domain name.  I am looking to enable a slightly different URL structure though and have turned to mod_rewrite to help me out.

The page is reachable at http://localhost/test but I want to rewrite that URL to appear as http://localhost/en-US/test.

The problem is I keep getting a code igniter (CI) 404.  I can confirm the mod_rewrite is reaching the CI index.php, but CI is failing to deliver the correct page.  Here's and example setup:

1) [Download a new instance of CI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) and place it in a subdirectory in the site root.  Name the CI folder "test".  It should be reachable now on a local server at http://localhost/test and you should see the default welcome view.

2) Create a .htaccess file in the server's root web directory. DO NOT place it in the CI "test" directory.  Add the following lines to it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en-US/test/?$ test/index.php [NC,L]
```

From my understanding of mod_rewrite, this should allow the URL http://localhost/en-US/test to render what is located at http://localhost/test.  It doesn't though.  I just get the CI version of a 404.  I need help figuring out how to resolve this.

Comment: Can you try: `RewriteRule ^en-US/test/?$ /test/index.php [NC,L,R]`

Comment: That would work except that it changes the URL.  That just becomes a redirect and I need to leave the new URL intact.

Comment: I know only for testing the other config issues I wanted to know if that redirect rule is indeed working for you?

Comment: Absolutely.  It resolved at the appropriate page.

Comment: ok provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm your question made me install CodeIgnoter and read its routing :)

Anyway have your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en-US/(test)/(.*)$ $1/$2 [NC,L]
```

Then replace this line in your /test/application/config/config.php`:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

It is by default set to:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

After this you can open this URL: `http://domain.comen-US/test/` to load CI home page in `/test/` dir.

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks.  PATH_INFO seemed to be the deciding factor there.  I even tried the original RewriteRule and it worked as well.  Thank you again for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. And thanks for forcing me to install CI :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html). Place this statement in your config/routes.php file AFTER the reserved routs.

```
$route['test'] = "en-US/test";
```

You can forget about htaccess when you have Codeigniter (most of the times).

Comment: That won't work as it needs to affect the URL before it reaches CI.  There are several instances of CI on the server.  This might work if CI was the only thing on the server and it could handle the routing on its own.